# LogicApp CRM connector create record gives a 500 error

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I've build a fairly simple LogicApp with the most recent version that came out about a week ago. It runs every hour and tries to create a record in CRM online. In the same manner I've created a LogicApp that retrieves records and that works.

The failed input and output looks like this:

```
{
    "host": {
        "api": {
            "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net/apim/dynamicscrmonline"
        },
        "connection": {
            "name": "subscriptions/6e779c81-1d0c-4df9-92b8-b287ba919b51/resourceGroups/spdev-eiramar/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/EE2AF043-71F0-4780-A8D1-25438A7746C0"
        }
    },
    "method": "post",
    "path": "/datasets/xxxx.crm4/tables/accounts/items",
    "body": {
        "name": "Test 1234"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-request-id": "d121f98c-3dd5-4e6d-899b-5150b17795a3",
        "cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "date": "Tue, 01 Mar 2016 12:27:09 GMT",
        "set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=xxxxx082f2bca2639f8a68e283db0eba612ddd71036cf5a5cf2597f99;Path=/;Domain=127.0.0.1",
        "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "x-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "x-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Unknown error.",
        "source": "127.0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have security roles setup to access the CRM Org, i.e. can you access the URL from browser? https://xxxx.crm4.dynamics.com

Update: Fix for this issue has been rolled out. Please retry your scenario.

Comment: Yes. As this a test environment, the user is connecting with the admin role. Also I wouldn't be able to read data if that would be the issue. And I'm able to post data through the new webapi as well.

Comment: We have identified the bug in Insert action for CRM. We are in the process of rolling out a fix. Will update once the fix has been rolled out to production.